# Duplicating java instance and storing within first instance, how to copy the values from the second instance back to the first?

Tags: java, performance

```
public class Example {
    public Example duplicate;

    public void duplicateState() {
        this.example = this.clone();
    }

    public void loadDuplicate() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Looking at the above example, you can see that I need to duplicate the Example instance. This is so that objects that want to modify Example must instead modify the duplicate, allowing the main instance to run routines without critical variables being changed. Periodically, the Example will load the duplicate's values and so that it can perform the routines with updated variables. Performance is critical in this. Does anyone know how to implement the `loadDuplicate` function in the fastest possible way, or are there any other ways to approach this problem?

Comment: Wow. What the point of doing this, can you explain to me in more detail? I've never seen something like this before.

Comment: `clone()` is for making duplicates, not serialization.  What are you really trying to accomplish here?  Your `example` field really confuses me.  Would it come into play in the `clone()`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I gave a bad example. I'll edit it.

Comment: Can the _saved state_ outlive the original object? Do you need to persist, or just keep state in running app for later revert?

Comment: See edits, sorry for the huge mistake. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the fastest performance, then both `duplicateState()` and `loadDuplicate()` should consist of a sequence of assignments of the fields of `Example`.

Both cloning and serialization will be significantly slower, though "how much" will depend on the number of fields and their types.

The other question is whether you need to do a deep or shallow copy of the state of an `Example`.  Clone (using the default `clone()` method will give you a shallow copy, and serialization will give you a (recursively) deep copy.

(FWIW - the last point is a reason why serialization will be slower than cloning.  Another is that serialization also needs to include metadata in the serial form ... and that's more data to be copied.)

Comment: No, shallow copy is fine. And yes I think i'll need to create a sequence of assignments. I was only wondering if there was a more efficient, built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use java's serialization feature, then later deserialize it.

See [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) for details

Comment: Bad mistake. Should have mentioned performance is a must. I'm looking for the fastest way. Sorry, editing now.

Comment: @sci: Doesn't functional correctness trump performance?  What on earth are you actually trying to do here?  BTW, you don't need to serialize to hard disk, you can serialize to something in memory like a byte array.

Comment: @scientiaesthete What evidence do you have that serialization is not fast? It is highly-optimized and highly-supported code, and best of all... it's already written

Comment: Agree with Bohemian. Java Serialization is a lot faster than people think. We do a lot of Java Serialization and are very happy with performance. Google ProtoBuf is faster and smaller but takes slightly more effort to program.

Comment: @scientiaesthete, `clone` isn't particularly fast either.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER, BUT A COMMENT**

if you use clone() and do all assignments yourself (as in below mentioned answer, which is actually correct), from maintenance perspective, beware that if you/some one else adds new field(s) to the Example class (say several months from now) you might need to update your mimic() method accordingly which can be easily missed. So unless you notice real performance issues (which am sure you won't), better to stick with inbuilt serialization.. just my 2 cents.. (i know you are ok with just shallow copy, still..)

p.s. couldnt comment as am a new user of SO

Comment: +1 - to give you some points so that you can comment next time :-).  (And a good answer too).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think that this will be any faster or better than serializing into a byte array (or some other in-memory structure) and de-serializing, but if you insist on "saving" the state with clone, just implement a method that does the opposite of your `clone()` method:

```
public class Example {
    public Example example;
    private Content content;
    //... more fields

    public void saveState() {
        this.example = this.clone();
    }

    public void loadState() {
        mimic( example );
    }

    public Example clone() {
        Example clone = new Example();
        clone.content = this.content;
        clone.example = this.example;
        //... you're doing this with all your fields I presume
        return clone;
    }

    public void mimic( Example model ) {
        this.content = model.content;
        this.example = model.example;
        //... and so on.
    }
}
```

Comment: So I must write clone and mimic method by hand. Thanks. I was just wondering if there was alternative to this.